# Cannot import a function from a file - get ImportError, but can import the entire file

Tags: python

In below code I get the following error:

```
import sys
import esig
import numpy as np

from preprocessing import preprocess_signature

from hyperparameters import hyperparameters


esig.set_backend("iisignature")

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)  

def calculate_signatures(split_stream, hps = hyperparameters):
    depth = hps.depth
    signatures = []


    for stream in split_stream:
        np_stream = np.array(stream)
        sig = esig.stream2sig(np_stream, depth)
        sig = preprocess_signature(sig, hps)
        signatures.append(sig)

    return signatures
```

```
from preprocessing import preprocess_signature
ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocess_signature' from 'preprocessing' (c:\Users\dmitr\Desktop\project work\preprocessing.py)
```

However when I change the code to be the following, it works as intended:

```
import sys
import esig
import numpy as np

import preprocessing

from hyperparameters import hyperparameters


esig.set_backend("iisignature")

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)  

def calculate_signatures(split_stream, hps = hyperparameters):
    depth = hps.depth
    signatures = []


    for stream in split_stream:
        np_stream = np.array(stream)
        sig = esig.stream2sig(np_stream, depth)
        sig = preprocessing.preprocess_signature(sig, hps)
        signatures.append(sig)

    return signatures
```

There are no typos, I am literally copy-pasting the name of the file and the function. There are no cycles of dependencies either.

Can someone please explain what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you ever actually call `calculate_signatures()`?  If your code examples are taken literally, then the second one never actually evaluates `preprocessing.preprocess_signature`, so there's no opportunity for its lack to be reported as an error.  (If there is actually a call to the function, then I would guess that `preprocess_signature` does not initially exist in the module, but something causes it to come into existence later.)

Comment: This is a module that I call somewhere else, so the call to the function is in another file. Also the preprocess_signature is defined as a function basically in the same way as calculate_signatures is here.

Comment: Can you share `preprocessing.py`?